# Making vertical scrollbar hover in visible area of the view

Tags: css

Is there a way to force a vertical bar via CSS to stay in the visible area of my view?

I'm using anvil works and have a container called data grid in that container 2 more containers:
data-row-panel - containing my headers of the table
repeating-panel - containing rows of data.

With the actual code my vertical bar is located a the end of my repeating-panel. In order to see the vertical bar I need to scroll to the end with horizontal scrollbar.

How to make it hover in the visible area? In anvil it's hard to edit the HTML side of this objects, because they are controlled by anvil code.

```
/* Data Grids */
/*styles data-row-panel containing header row to be single row only and add a bar*/
.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .anvil-data-row-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: min-content;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*styles repeating panel to be single row only and add a bar*/
.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .repeating-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: min-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;/*add vetical bar*/
  max-height: 450px;/*max height*/
}
/*container holding the data row and repeating panel
.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .data-grid-child-panel {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

The code generates something like that as html structure:

```
 <div class="data-grid-child-panel">
     <div class="anvil-data-row-panel"></div>
     <div class="repeating-panel"></div>
</div>
```

HTML strucutre. The rest is controlled by code.

```
<div class="structure">
  <div class="app-bar" anvil-drop-container=".anvil-container" anvil-drop-redirect=".placeholder">
    <a class="sidebar-toggle" anvil-if-slot-empty="top-left-btn" anvil-hide-if-slot-empty="left-nav" anvil-drop-slot="top-left-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <a class="sidebar-toggle anvil-designer-only" anvil-if-slot-empty="top-left-btn" anvil-if-slot-empty="left-nav" anvil-drop-slot="top-left-btn"><i class="fa fa-blank"></i></a>
    <div class="top-left-btn" anvil-slot="top-left-btn"></div>
    <div class="title" anvil-slot="title">
      <div class="placeholder anvil-designer-only" anvil-if-slot-empty="title" anvil-drop-here>Drop title here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="app-bar-nav" anvil-slot="nav-right">
      <div class="placeholder anvil-designer-only" anvil-if-slot-empty="nav-right" anvil-drop-here>Drop a FlowPanel here</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-holder">
    <div class="left-nav anvil-measure-this" anvil-slot-repeat="left-nav" anvil-drop-container=">.anvil-container">
    </div>
    <div class="left-nav-placeholder anvil-designer-only" anvil-if-slot-empty="left-nav" anvil-drop-slot="left-nav">
      <div class="prompt">To add a sidebar, drop a ColumnPanel here.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div anvil-slot-repeat="default" class="anvil-measure-this"></div>
      <div class="placeholder drop-here" anvil-if-slot-empty="default" anvil-drop-slot="default">Drop a ColumnPanel here.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-shield"></div>
</div>
<div anvil-drop-default anvil-drop-redirect=".placeholder" anvil-drop-container=".anvil-container"></div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to assist here without seeing your HTML/markup; please add that to your question. In the meantime, are you able to use something like `position: fixed`?

Comment: yes, i put it but assigning it to the repeating-panel container don't affect the position of the y-scrollbar. It is still at the end. Sadly the End-HTML structure is controlled by the anvil works builder. that is the reason it's hard to make some changes. The easiest way would be using HTML to fix the location, but I'm limited to CSS, or just decide to make the whole page with HTML instead of the anvil creator.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to a problem. Maybe it's not the best way to solve it but it works.

In my parent container I have both header row and data rows. adding a vertical scroll and height limitation to the parent container cause scrolling of header and rows together. So scrolling down meant header dissappear. Thanks for the hint with position attribute.

I just sticked my header row at the top of the parent container and set it's z-index to be on top of the data rows container. Both scrollbars ar visible because my parent container is limited to my visible area only and they won't move.

```
.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .anvil-data-row-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;/*all columns are ordered as a single row*/
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: min-content;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: sticky;/*by setting it it will get stick to the top and it hoovers over the scrolled page as header*/
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;/*forces to be always at the top to cover the scrolled rows of 2nd container*/
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .anvil-data-row-panel > div {
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
}

.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .anvil-data-row-panel > div:first-child {
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .anvil-data-row-panel > div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
}

/*styles repeating panel to be single row only and add a bar*/
.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .repeating-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: min-content;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0; /* lower z-index than anvil-data-row-panel */
}

.anvil-role-tonal-data-grid .data-grid-child-panel {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;/*add vetical bar*/
  max-height: 450px;
}
```